# Check if User has clicked "Ok" for "onbeforeunload event"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking when the user closes the browser window, if he says ok, how i do I trigger some action, like opening another window or saving a form. If he chooses "cancel", it should stay in the same page (which is working now). pls share some idea on how to approach this issue

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/sk5yc/13/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** react to the user clicking on the "Leave this page" button. This is by design of the browser: **if the user wants to leave, let him go**.

If the user chooses to cancel, you can try a technique found in [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651049/177710) to execute some custom code like saving changes or the like.