# Intercept selection in window.onbeforeunload dialog

Tags: javascript, code-behind

in my web application if the user leaves the current page without having saved changes in the form a pop up window is opened to alert him about that.

For the pop up I use some scripts code injected from codebehind (C#):

```
var Confirm = true;
window.onbeforeunload = confirmClose;  
function confirmClose() 
{
   if (!Confirm) return;

   if(/*CHECK CHANGE CONDITION IS TRUE*/)
      { return " + WARN_message + "; }
}
```

I would need to intercept whether the user click on cancel or ok button.

I tried like:

```
var button_pressed = window.onbeforeunload = confirmClose;
```

But it returns always true.

How can get which button was pressed?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if User has clicked "Ok" for "onbeforeunload event"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725680/check-if-user-has-clicked-ok-for-onbeforeunload-event)

Comment: which is a duplicate of [Way to know if user clicked Cancel on a Javascript onbeforeunload Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. There is no event associated with the buttons.
What you might be able to do was to see if the user came back by setting a value or perhaps a cookie in the page in the onbeforeunload and test if it is there after some time has passed

but see the duplicate [Way to know if user clicked Cancel on a Javascript onbeforeunload Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog)