# How to execute ajax function onbeforeunload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm developing a php/javascript chat.

When the user logs in, his/her username is inserted in a MySQL table called `queue`.
This insert returns the `mysql_insert_id()` that will be stored in a session variable called `$_SESSION['CHAT_QUEUE_ID']`

I need the MySQL table row to be deleted when the user closes the page.

I tried the following, but without success:

*js file*

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeSession;
function closeSession(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/chat/process/chat.php",
        type: "GET"
    });
    return "disconnected";
}
```

*chat.php*

```
$delete= "DELETE FROM queue WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['CHAT_QUEUE_ID'];
// query, etc
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that browser support for ``onbeforeunload`` is limited? E.g. opera doesn't support it.

Comment: I had not thought of that. any suggestion?

Comment: The common method is to define a timeout. If a user hadn't had an activity for a specific amount of time he is disconnected.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You fire your ajax async (default for jquery - ajax). But the browser won't wait for anything on unload.

try setting `async : false` in the ajax-settings. But you can never be sure that this will work in all browsers everytime.

see the comment here:
http://api.jquery.com/unload/#dsq-comment-body-132164390

Comment: It works perfectly. should have thought of that before... THANKS!

Comment: Also - if you are triggering the same functional ajax call that you use asynchronously (or a number of ajax calls) you can set them to async globally in your onbeforeunload statement: 
  $.ajaxSetup({
   async: false
  });

Comment: A useful followup on setting async=false to reset to async=true: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4651049/449444

Comment: Do you know why we have to set it to be synchronous ? As what we want is to send data to the server but don't care about server response since the data is passed ?