# Send AJAX to server beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, onbeforeunload

[So supposedly starting at Firefox > 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398772/firefox-4-onbeforeunload-custom-message), binding the window jQuery object to `beforeunload` doesn't work anymore.

What'd I'd like to do is submit an AJAX post to delete my server's memcache data.

When I refresh the only open tab, I can see that the `beforeunload` event is called in both firefox and chrome with the following code as evidenced by the console.log message, "firefox/NON-firefox delete". The problem is that I never see the console.log message "memcache delete" indicating that my server never saw the `$.ajax` request.

I realize it is bad to do browser sniffing and that there is no difference between what's included in the if and else statements. I'm merely showing code for what I've tried unsuccessfully in Firefox.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
  if(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && new Number(RegExp.$1) >= 4) {
    console.log('firefox delete');
     memcacheDelete();
     return null;
  } 
  else {
    console.log('NON-firefox delete');
    memcacheDelete();
    return null;
  }
});

function memcacheDelete() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "/memcache/delete", 
      type: "post",
      data:{}, 
      success:function(){
          console.log('memcache deleted');
      }//success
  }); //ajax
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Ajax is asynchronous.***

When you refresh (or close)your browser, `beforeunload` is being called. And it means as soon as `beforeunload` is finished executing, page will refresh (or close).

When you do an ajax request, (since its asynchronous) javascript interpreter does not wait for ajax `success` event to be executed and moves down finishing the execution of `beforeunload`.

`success` of ajax is supposed to be called after few secs, but you dont see it as page has been refreshed / closed.

**Side note:**

*`.success()` method is deprecated and is replaced by the `.done()` method*

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Comment: yes...the way i understand asynch calls this is what i thought...+1

Comment: @Jashwant, thanks for the explanation.Though, I have evidence that the memcache delete succeeded when using Chrome after closing/re-opening the browser, but it is still **not** deleting with firefox. There seems to be something else going on here..would converting the `$.ajax` to synchronous, `async:false`, help?

Comment: It looks like changing [the `$.ajax` option `async` to `false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) corrects the problem. Is there any reason one wouldn't want to do that?

Comment: Usually ajax is `true`, as we dont want to wait until ajax completion. If you'll set `async` to `false` , your javascript code after ajax call wont execute until server's response. In your case specifically, I think refreshing / closing may take few seconds (until ajax is complete)

Comment: @jashwant, +1 for the comment about `done()` replacing `success()`. I didn't know that. It would seem that waiting in my case is ok as I'm storing state data in memcache and don't want to confuse the user by showing "old" data if the memcache doesn't delete (and subsequently get refreshed upon the reload). So better to wait than show bad data, don't you think?

Comment: Yes. all options for developer's sake . Use the one that suits you :)

Comment: deos it works for chrome and safari?

Comment: It should. Test yourself and do let the community know :)

Answer (score 8):

Just for sake of completion, here's what I did, thanks to @Jashwant for the guidance:
I noticed that [this other SO Q&A suggested the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701734/how-to-execute-ajax-function-onbeforeunload?rq=1).
*The KEY is* the `async:true(false)` in the `$.ajax` call below:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
  if(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && new Number(RegExp.$1) >= 4) {
    console.log('firefox delete');
     var data={async:false};
     memcacheDelete(data);
     return null;
  } 
  else {
    console.log('NON-firefox delete');
     var data={async:true};
     memcacheDelete(data);
    return null;
  }
});

function memcacheDelete(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/memcache/delete", 
    type: "post",
    data:{}, 
    async:data.async,
    success:function(){
      console.log('memcache deleted');
    }//success
  }); //ajax
}
```

Comment: Just to feed my curiosity. What is the meaning (use) of `&& new Number(RegExp.$1) >= 4` in your Firefox-detecting routine (if)? Just assuring, that Firefox is in version 4 or newer?