# Any button on page to run a session save?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, session-cookies

I have a form that needs to be submitted on all button presses or whenever a user leaves the page, is that possible if so how?

Comment: "a form that needs to be submitted ... whenever a user leaves the page" - that is just incredibly bad design and user experience, why do you need this?

Comment: I would rather implement AJAX to do this. Then you can - maybe - show a "Closing application.." or something when user leaves page. You can do this by binding an AJAX call to the 'onunload' Javascript event.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929832/send-ajax-to-server-beforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery to detect if a user leaves the page.
https://api.jquery.com/unload/

```
    $( window ).unload(function() {
         //call your function here that executes the form
         return "Handler for .unload() called.";
   });
```

using jquery to detect button presses.

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonCLass', function(){
 //code here
 })
```