# How to make angularjs $http POST call when user refresh a page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, rootscope

controller:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function ($scope, $http) {     
        $templateCache.removeAll();
        alert("refresh.....");
        $http({
            url: '/angularjs-restful/check/check-session',
            method: "POST",
            data: {},
            isArray: false
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            alert("success.....");
            console.log('status: ' + status);
            console.log('data: ' + data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            alert('error');
        });        
        alert("end.....");
    });       
});
```

I need to make an AJAX call when a user hit f5 on keyboard or manually refresh the page with a mouse. How can I achieve this?
the url is a rest service that either return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)  function to listen to the unload event which should fire on f5.

```
function ctrl($scope, $window) {
    angular.element($window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        console.log('do ajax call');
    });
}
```

Comment: I would instead recommend binding to the `beforeunload` event using the `$window` service in case you need to test your AJAX call through mocks. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LkPJX/

Comment: I tried and still does not work. How do I add your code onto the code that I posted above? When I refresh the page, the alert("refresh.....") is working fine and after the alert, I need to make an ajax call using $http to call a service...I added the code that you provided "angular.element($window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        console.log('do ajax call');
    });" but it does not run after alert has finished

Comment: If testing on IE [you'll need to also call `$rootScope.$digest()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38251551/1108708).