# Using onbeforeunload in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logout, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have been trying to call a a logout service from whitin onunload or onbeforeunload window events.

This is because I needed to logout upon closure of window or a tab. 
I set $window.onbeforeunload within the run() block.

$window.onbeforeunload worked fine when I wanted to show a warning to the user upon closure of tab or window. But, when I tried to call a logout function from within the onbeforeunload event, the function was not called.

I tried calling the $http from within run() block or calling it from a data service, but the result was the same.

How can I solve this?

Comment: seems that the problem is that angularJS $http service is always asynchronous, while in onbeforeunload a synchronous call is required.
This means that I needed to use a synchronous call written in javascript. Something like: '
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "services/logout", false);  // synchronous request
xhr.send(null);' 
This I found from: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689233/how-to-send-an-http-request-onbefor‌​eunload-in-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689233/how-to-send-an-http-request-onbefor‌​eunload-in-angularjs)

Comment: Additional information about synchronous calls in javascript: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example_.231.3A_Automatic_logout_before_exit)