# how to hit a webservice while closing the browser window or tab?

Tags: javascript, web-services, browser-close

I am facing a problem i need to hit the webservice before closing the tab.
i am using this

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    return "Write something clever here...";
}
</script>   

 <body  onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
```

> i don't know where i hit the webservice while closing the tab its show
>   the prompt where show stay on page and leave the page. So i
>   implemented the condition if leave then hit the webservice otherwise
>   its remain same

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701734/how-to-execute-ajax-function-onbeforeunload

Comment: i could not understand i need to hit the webservice should i use javascript or jquery

Comment: <script>
$(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
              url: "/tabdisconnect/",
              data: { user: '1' }
             })
                .done(function( data ) {
     });
            }, 1000);
        },1);
        return '';
    });
});        
           </script>

Comment: i am using above but its trigger also while i refersh the page