# do something if user chooses to stay on the page

Tags: javascript, browser-refresh

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript) to determine if user has clicked refresh button of the browser.

It gives the user an option to stay on the page or to leave the page.

If user chooses to stay on the page, I want to do something (call some method). Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/276739/704894

Comment: @Miszy: Not really a duplicate. He is trying to do something when the user clicks cancel. He hasn't indicated that he's trying to alter the default message that is displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog