# cursor not stopping until button click completes in window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have below javascript code for window.onbeforeunload.  I am calling code behind button click method when pressed browser back button.

Now the problem is cursor is not stopping until `$("#buttonclientid").click()` completes. Just calling the method and moving to next statement. How to hold or stop cursor until `$("#buttonclientid").click()` complete and then move to next step?

```
var form_has_been_modified = 0;
  $(function () {

      $("input").keyup(function () {
          form_has_been_modified = 1;
      })
      window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          if (!form_has_been_modified) {
                  return;
          }
                doYouWantTo();
      }

   });

   function doYouWantTo(){
        doIt=confirm('Do you want to save the data before leave the page?');
        if (doIt) {
             var returnbutton;
             //cursor should stop here until click function completes.
             returnbutton = $("#buttonclientid").click();
        }
        else{

            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean about the cursor "not stopping"?  What cursor?  Where is it going? Why is it moving?

Comment: I mean to say after clicking on "BACK" button on browser and it is executing next step without completing $("#buttonclientid").click(); function and going back page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies in the fact that your `doYouWantTo` function does not return a value to be passed back into `onbeforeunload` so it is leaving the page while also running the function, rather than waiting until it completes.

Your best action here would be something like:

```
return doYouWantTo()
....
if(doIt) {
    $('#buttonclientid').click(function() { // unsure if you can attach callback to click but idea is same
        return true;
    });
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what you mean "attach callback ". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean a callback to indicate that your 'save' function has completed. I don't believe you can utilize callbacks on click events so maybe take your `click` code out and place it in a separate function `saveData(callback)` and in the `if(doIt)` branch replace  `$('#buttonclientid').click(` with `saveData(`

Answer (score 0):

When binding an event handler to the `onbeforeunload` event, it should return one of two things:

- if you want a confirm to show, your handler should return a string
- if you don't want a confirm to show (skip the handler), return `undefined` (or don't return at all, same effect)

That being said, your code should look something like this:

```
var form_has_been_modified = false;
$("input").keyup(function () {
    form_has_been_modified = true; // use a boolean :P
});

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (form_has_been_modified) {
        return 'Do you want to save the data before leave the page?';
    } else {
        return undefined; // this can be omitted if you prefer
    }
};
```

The only way to tell what a user clicked on the system dialog is to use `setTimeout`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog) for details on that subject.