# How to trigger an exit popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make an exit popup on my website. I've prepared my modal but can't find "a good way" to detect a moment when a user is about to leave the website. I've read some other posts on this subject and found this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mouseleave(function(e) {
    if(e.clientY < 0) {
      $('#exit').modal('show')
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately this solution doesn't work on IE and Edge. What's the better way of doing it?

**UPDATE:**
Let me be more precise. I want to achieve something like [this](http://blog.wishpond.com/post/93315626207/5-exit-popups-you-need-to-know-about). I assumed that the best way is to detect when a mouse leaves a document.

Comment: That code basically checks to see if the mouse cursor is above the top of the document window.  Is that what you're trying to do??

Comment: Yes, it is. As I said - the result is fine, but it's doesn't work on all browsers.

Comment: Try this on `mousemove`. It should work...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068912/how-to-control-when-closing-a-window

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is done using the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event on the window.  This should be assigned to a function that returns the text you wish to display to the user when they are leaving the page.  For example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?"
}
```

This will result in a confirmation window when the user tries to leave the page for any reason.  If you don't want it to display on internal links, you will need to use javascript to unassign the event before the navigation occurs.

Comment: Also, this won't work in Chrome. It just keeps saying "Changes won't be saved..."

Comment: But now I'm not able to trigger my modal, am I?

Comment: @bloo79 Yes, you can't trigger the modal.

Comment: Yeah in modern browsers they show a generic string instead of the results of the function.  There is unfortunately no easy way to use your own dialog to prevent the user from leaving the page (for good reason -- malicious sites used to be able to almost completely prevent users from leaving)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    // do stuff with your modal here
}
```

do what you want inside the callback function, but the onbeforeunload event is the one you will want to handle

Comment: This doesn't work. It shows it and closes the browser.

Comment: before unload is when you're leaving the page, not moving the mouse away.

Comment: you'll want to work with whatever the #exit modal is - we don't know that from what you posted.  it's just an example.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm, "before unload" is when OP said they're trying to trigger a popup.  this code still won't work, but not for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: I see your point, but if you look at comments `That code basically checks to see if the mouse cursor is above the top of the document window. Is that what you're trying to do??` and the OP's response `Yes, it is. As I said - the result is fine, but it's doesn't work on all browsers`. I think the OP is confused on what he wants.

Comment: @Al for the record those comments were added after (or the same time as) I posted my answer.  but I agree - not sure at this point what behavior the OP wants, so we'll see