# ZK Framework: How to capture Buttons click event "Leave this page", "Stay on this page" of window popped up by Clients.confirmClose()?

Tags: java, zk

Clients.confirmClose() method in ZK Framework pops up window saying "Are you sure want to leave this page?" with two buttons- leave this page , stay on this page. I want to perform some operation when user clicks on buttons either "leave this page" or "stay on this page"? Can any body suggest me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens in [mount.js](https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/e279eece5c036b6c452b80b9ab6d8d86b7a4a73c/zk/src/archive/web/js/zk/mount.js); search for `window.onbeforeunload`.

The standard JavaScript event `onbeforeunload` shows the dialog when the registered function returns a string ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)).

If you want to override the behavior, you need to install your own handler and use the `setTimeout()` trick described in this question: [Way to know if user clicked Cancel on a Javascript onbeforeunload Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog)

Note that it's not possible to do something in the "leave page" case since the browser will have killed all the JavaScript that you have written at this time.