# How to know return of window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

i have JS function window.onbeforeunload which returns a msg and browser shows that in confirmbox. Now how will i know whether user clicked on leave that page or stay on page ?

```
Javascript

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
 return "Click STAY ON PAGE then SAVE to save any data you've entered.\n If you've already SAVED select LEAVE PAGE to continue."; 
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/Ly6WE/

Comment: If the user is no longer on the page, chances are they left.

Comment: @Shomz but if they stay i need to change value of variable. how do i do that ?

Comment: onunload won't be called if they confirmed to leave.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti M not concerned abt them leaving the page. i am concerned if they stay. i need to update one variable. anyway to do it ?

Comment: You can't really. You could set a timeout function see [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog

Comment: @jbyrne2007 Of course you can, see my answer.

Comment: @Shomz I don't really think that is a solution. The value has changed when you have fired the event not after it has unloaded. Either way if they stay or leave that value has changed before they have made a decision.

Comment: @jbyrne2007 OP needs an updated variable if they stay. I understand what you're saying and yes, in many cases my solution won't work, but in this case it works just fine because the problem here is more about thinking outside the box than coding.

Comment: @Shomz I agree in some instances this may work and it is thinking outside the box, but the question was how he will know if the user has clicked to leave or stay on the page, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Update the variable anyway. If they stayed, you get what you want; if they left, it won't matter.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   var myVariable = 'updated value'; // of course, var not from this scope
   return "Click STAY ON PAGE then SAVE to save any data you've entered.\n If you've already SAVED select LEAVE PAGE to continue."; 
}
```

See what happens to `x` after you try to leave: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/Ly6WE/3/

Answer (score 0):

Crossbrowser code which realize this:

```
    (function() {
        function beforeUnload(event) {
            event = event || window.event;

            var confirmationMessage = 'Changes not saved';

            event.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
            return confirmationMessage;
        }

        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnload, false);
    })();
```

And that's how this will work. When `beforeUnload` triggered, user will get confirmation box with 2 button "Leave this page" and "Stay on this page". When user press "Leave this page" -> tab will close. But when user click "Stay on this page" -> nothing will happen and user don't lose data.

Comment: This is pretty much the same that OP originally had.

Comment: 1. event better get from window.event if event will be undefined.
2. If ```return``` not works, then need add ```event.returnValue``` and this will work.

Of course this is pretty much the same, but it contains a few improvements that works better.