# Javascript -Way to detect on what option user clicks on Navigation Popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When a user closes a browser tab, I want to make an ajax request based on what option he clicks.

If he clicks on Leave this page -> Ajax Call 1

If he clicks on Stay on this page -> Ajax Call 2

here is how my code looks like now

I want to do this ajax call after what the user has selected any one of the option. But currently the ajax call runs automatically if the user tries to close the tab

```
window.onbeforeunload = userConfirmation;

function userConfirmation(){
  var cookieName  = $.trim("<?php echo $this->uri->segment('5') ?>");
  var toValue     = $.trim($('#toValue').val());
  document.cookie = cookieName+'=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;path=/';
  var confirmation = 'The message will be discarded.';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.'index.php/admin/mail_actions/deleteSessionDatas' ?>",
    data: {'toValue':toValue},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      var response = $.trim(response);
    }
  });
  return confirmation;
}
```

Comment: did you mean "page tab" instead of "browser tab" ?

Comment: yes... an individual page tab

Comment: please post the html of `Leave this page` and `Stay on this page`

Comment: no..I want to make an ajax request based on the click

Comment: I'm sorry but not following you, please edit your question in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Right now, wen user tries to close a tab I am successful in bringing browser's default confirm box where it asks the user whether to stay in that page or leave the page. Now I want to detect what option the user has selected from that confirm box and i will do any custom action like sending an ajax request  based on that selection. Hope that clears your doubt

Comment: I think you can check the response inside a single if (or saving the functions return value in a variable) like when you use JS confirm(). On the other hand, if the user clicks leave, all scripts will stop (IMO) so technically you don't need to check anything...

Comment: Can u post a working code for that?

Comment: What you're trying to do is to add an `after-beforeunload` event, which is impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to know if user clicked Cancel on a Javascript onbeforeunload Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650692/way-to-know-if-user-clicked-cancel-on-a-javascript-onbeforeunload-dialog)

Comment: You may want to do ajax query synchronously.

Comment: I do not see why you didn't use the .click() method? this is supported by jquery***, or even to run an ajax functions...

Comment: Not enough information, do you have a fiddle of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I put forward that this is a hack and not **the** solution, this is just **a** solution.

In order to execute a piece of code <sub>(this is suitable not just for `AJAX`)</sub> only when the user clicks on <kbd>**Stay on this page**</kbd> you have to make it run asychronously, thus `javaScript` keeps running synchronous code (the `return` statement).

`jQuery.ajax()` calls must include the `async: true` parameter, then the code to be executed **after** user's click must be included in a `setTimeout()` function with the proper timeout <sub>(if the page takes too much time to unload the timeout must be higher)</sub>

```
var stayHere = ""; // this variable helps with the "stay on this page"_code cancellation when user chooses "leave this page"
window.onbeforeunload = userConfirmation;

function userConfirmation() {
    var confirmation = "Your edits will be lost";
    stayHere = setTimeout(function() { // the timeout will be cleared on "leave this page" click
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax-call.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {chosenOpt: "stay"},
            async: true, // important
            success: function(data) { console.log(data);},
            error: function() { alert("error");}
        });
    }, 2000); // Here you must put the proper time for your application
    return confirmation;
}
```

**How to run code if user clicks on <kbd>Leave this page</kbd>**

If the user chooses to leave the page, then the page starts to unload and when it has completely unloaded the `unload` event fires, so I'll put code in its listener:

```
jQuery(window).on("unload", function() {
clearTimeout(stayHere); // This is another assurance that the "stay here"_code is not executed
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax-call.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { chosenOpt: "leave"},
    async: false, // If set to "true" the code will not be executed
    success: function(data) { console.log(data);},
    error: function() { console.log("Error");} // In chrome, on unload, an alert will be blocked
});
```

});

**Note:** be careful with the code that executes inside an `unload` handler. Since the `unload` event fires **after everything is unloaded**, none object in the page is still available.

Here is a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j96mbedh/4/) to see how does it works.

The `ajax-call.php` contains just

```
echo $_POST["chosenOpt"] . "_" . rand(1, 9999);
```

And the output will be `leave_[number]` on <kbd>Leave this page</kbd> and `stay_[number]` on <kbd>Stay on this page</kbd>

**Note:** You can see `leave_[number]` only **refreshing** the page and if *Preserve Log* is checked in console.

Comment: This is tested and with the given "settings" (stay_on_page's ajax `async: true`, leave_the_page's ajax `async: false`, the asynchronous with `setTimeout()` function and the `clearTimeout(stayHere)` function to stop the stay_on_page's code to be executed) in about 3000 (this is not a joke) attempts in Chrome, Firefox and IE this works perfectly with no errors!! **;)**

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if it fits to your request, it took me hours to develop it in the best way!! **XD**

Comment: Hi @IdentityUnkn0wn, I have added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j96mbedh/4/) to show you how does it works, but it hasn't `AJAX`. I hope it will be of help.

Comment: This worked brilliantly...thts what I needed. thnx for your time and effort