# How to check whether before unload confirmation box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

My code is like this:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.post('ajax_url',$('form').serialize());
    return "are you sure";
}
```

Now I want to send an ajax request if window is closed, but not when he stayed on the page by clicking <kbd>cancel</kbd> button.

Comment: may be this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4651049/1059101

Answer (score 1):

move your ajax to an unload event handler

```
window.onunload = function() {
   $.post('ajax_url',$('form').serialize());
}
```

Comment: thanks , but unload event is not working properly in chrome when window is closed

Answer (score 0):

[Answer taken from this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651049/1059101)

In your case you might do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
        $.post('ajax_url',$('form').serialize());
   }, 1000);
},1);
return 'are you sure';
```

---

The code within the first setTimeout method has a delay of 1ms.
This is just to add the function into the UI queue. *Since setTimeout runs asynchronously* the `Javascript interpreter will continue by directly calling the return statement`, which in turn triggers the browsers modal dialog.

This will block the UI queue and the code from the first setTimeout is not executed, until the modal is closed.

**If the user pressed cancel**, it will trigger another setTimeout which fires in about one second.
**If the user confirmed with ok**, the user will redirect and the second setTimeout is never fired.

Comment: Thanks , But I want to send the request when window is closed , not when cancel button is pressed :-)